# Custom ListView with button, the list item is unclickable

Tags: android, listview, adapter

I have a custom list view,List view item has a button, I can't click on the list item itself, the only thing is clickable is the button.

> I want to be able to click the list item and the button separately.

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View itemView = convertView;
    itemView = (itemView == null) ? inflater.inflate(R.layout.listview_layout, null) : itemView;
    TextView textViewName = itemView.findViewById(R.id.headtext);
    TextView textViewDescription = itemView.findViewById(R.id.disctext);
    ImageView stationImage = itemView.findViewById(R.id.image);
    //ImageButton favButton = itemView.findViewById(R.id.favbutton);
    FloatingActionButton favButton = itemView.findViewById(R.id.favbutton);
    Station selectedStation = stations.get(position);
    textViewName.setText(selectedStation.getStationName());
    textViewDescription.setText(selectedStation.getDescription());
    stationImage.setImageResource(selectedStation.getStationImg());
    checkFavForBtn(favButton, selectedStation);

    favButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            try {
                LibraryUtil.setFavoritesLibrary(selectedStation, context);
                System.out.println("Saving");
            } catch (IOException | ClassNotFoundException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            checkFavForBtn(favButton, selectedStation);
            //notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    });
    return itemView;
}
```

click listener for the listview -

```
       lst.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            //my code
        }
    });
```

What should I do?
Thank you in advance!

**Found the solution**

```
        itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent serviceIntent = new Intent(finalItemView.getContext(), BackgroundSoundService.class);
            serviceIntent.putExtra("position", position);
            serviceIntent.putExtra("whatlibrary", 1);
            finalItemView.getContext().startService(serviceIntent);

        }
    });

    favButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            try {
                LibraryUtil.setFavoritesLibrary(selectedStation, context);
                System.out.println("Saving");
            } catch (IOException | ClassNotFoundException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            checkFavForBtn(favButton, selectedStation);
            //notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    });
```

Comment: share your xml file.

Comment: I am trying, keep getting,  "mostly code....."

Comment: did you add onItemClickListener for listView?

Comment: Add a click listener to the root view of the list item

Comment: yes off course.

Comment: then remove it , add itemView.setOnClickListener...

Comment: @TsurYohananov did you try my answer

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Custom Adapter for List View](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8166497/custom-adapter-for-list-view)

Answer (score 1):

```
You are handling favbutton on click listener .thats why only button click is working.
```

try to handle whole view onclickListiner

like below

```
 //  onClick listener for view
    itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // do something when the corky is clicked
        }
    });
```

second way :

implement like this 
public class BookListActivity extends Activity implements OnItemClickListener

and over ride the method like below

```
@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2, long arg3) {`\
```

//do your on click functionalities here
    }

Hope it is helpful for you.Let me know

Answer (score 0):

Add this in your button

```
   android:focusable="false"
   android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
```

Since the button is clickable, the whole view will not be focused.
Adding this line will help you to click both item view as well as button in view

Answer (score 0):

A.F.A.I.K.

When you are using [Button](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Button.html) or [ImageView](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.html) in `list_item`,

you will not able to use [OnItemClickListener](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AdapterView.OnItemClickListener.html) properly.

because They have their own focus, so it will not let `list_item` focus.

You have to set [OnClickListener](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.OnClickListener.html) separately on button and `list_item`'s parent layout.